# Node.js path.join() in php

Tags: php, regex

I had some good experience with `node.js`, and I found `path.join()` very useful function, since it will take care that there is no extra slashes in the `URL`.

I was wondering if something can be done in php to join relative part of an url and not end up with extra slashes in the url?

Comment: How on Earth is this related with node.js

Comment: @ankitbug94 removed the tag.